# Populating html table from external php to allow highlighting on hover over row

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I am trying to populate a html table based on a select box (with staff numbers)  changing. The data is being retrieved from a mysql database. I then want to highlight a row when it is hovered over using jquery.

Am I going about this the right way?

main.php

```
<div id="logHistory">
      <label id="historyTableLabel">Your Log History</label>
        <table id="logTable">
          <tr id="headers">
            <td>Log Date</td>
            <td>LogType</td>
            <td>Start Time</td>
            <td>End Time</td>
            <td>Duration</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
     </div>
```

select.php

```
    $staffNum = isset($_POST['staffNumber']) ? $_POST['staffNumber'] : 0;
        if($staffNum > 0)
        {
            populateLogHistory($con, $staffNum);
        }

        function populateLogHistory($con, $staffNum)
        {
            //Retrieve data from entries table
            $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT EntryID, LogDate, LogType, StartTime, StartDate, FinishTime, FinishDate FROM Entries WHERE StaffNumber=$staffNum");

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $entryID = $row['EntryID'];
                $logDate = $row['LogDate'];
                $logTypeID = $row['LogType'];
                $resulting = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT LogType FROM logType WHERE LogTypeID=$logTypeID");
                $logTypeStr = mysqli_fetch_array($resulting);
                $startDate = $row['StartDate'];
                $startTime = $row['StartTime'];
                $start = $startDate . " " . $startTime;
                $start = new DateTime($start);
                $finishDate = $row['FinishDate'];
                $finishTime = $row['FinishTime'];
                $finish = $finishDate . " " . $finishTime;
                $finish = new DateTime($finish);
                $duration = $start->diff($finish);

                echo "<tr id=".$entryID.">";
                echo "<td>".$logDate."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$logTypeStr[0]."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$startTime."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$finishTime."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$duration->h."hr ".$duration->i."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
```

jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("#staffMember").change(function()
  {
    //Check the mandatory first
    var selectedIndex = $("#staffMember").prop('selectedIndex');
    isMandatory(selectedIndex, $(this));

    if(selectedIndex != -1)
    {
      //If there is a staff number call the select to populate the log history
      var staffNum = $("#staffMember").val();
      var dataString = 'staffNumber=' + staffNum;

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "select.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html)
        {
          $("#logTable").html(html);
        }
      });
    }
  }).change();
});
```

Comment: Why not just use CSS for the hovering part and focus the javascript on populating your table.

Comment: At a later stage of this I want to be able to click on the row to call another sql query

Comment: So when the table is populated, you want the result to be click-able to show more data?

Comment: Yes I want to be able to populate several boxes in a form with the data tied into the row that is clicked. That was why I had used entryID as on of the tr ids

Comment: Do you successfully populate your table? What is the problem?

Comment: I do successfully populate the table but I cant get to the individual row to highlight/pick up the click event. I can highlight the header separately to the data row but the data rows just highlights the entire block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this CSS for the hovering part:

```
.datarow:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Assuming that you put a `class` tag to your populated row:

```
echo '<tr id="'.$entryID.'" class="datarow">';
```

---

For the populating part, use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for every call so you can still do another call on Javascript DOM elements.

```
$(document).on("change", "#staffMember", function(){
```

And if you want to do another event handler on the populated data, let's put it as a `class` tag instead and the data (`$entryID`) will be on another `data` tag.

```
echo '<tr data-artid="'.$entryID.'" class="datarow">';
```

So when you try to call it, you can just do:

```
$(document).on("click", ".datarow", function(){

    var entryid = $(this).attr('data-artid'); /* ENTRY ID OF THE CLICKED ROW */
```

Comment: Great that has solved my issue. Thank you for your help